# Which branch of computer science uses mathematical optimization the most?

Tags: optimization

I am beginning with my masters degree in mathematics and I will specialize in optimization theory. My minor is computer science and wanted to know which branch of computer science fits my specialization(optimization theory) the best.

I know that machine learning involves some optimization theory (I don't know how much though...)

Comment: Im still an undergrad, but I know that in machine learning (in supervised learning specifically) there is use of basic (at least from what I saw) optimization theory.
Anyways, if I remember correctly, there *should* be a specialization in optimization theory in most universities. Doesn't your university have such a specialization?

Comment: Machine learning problems can sometimes be formulized as optimization problems and can be solved with such techniques, for example, stochastic gradient descent is a very simple way to solve convex optimization problems, such as the SVM (Support Vector Machine) problem in machine learning.